# Are Helper Classes or Categories available in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, helper, objective-c-category

In `Objective-C` you can create a Category which allows you to add extra functionality to an existing class eg `NSString`.  In `Delphi` you can create a Helper class that again allow you to add functionality to an existing class.  in `Javascript` you can add functions to the class prototype.

Is there anything similar available for `PHP`?

Comment: I'm sorry but I think there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) is what you are looking for, but it only supports for >=5.4.

Comment: There not quite the same, but they may be just what I'm looking for.